# Discrete Time to Continuous Time and Summation of Two Geometric Brownian Motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Could someone please suggest with detailed steps and/or a reference,

1) How to convert the below discrete time summation to continuous time form and write it as an integral?

2) Any methods to solve it?

$$
\sum_{t=0}^{T}\left[\left(K-X_{t}\right)\right]\left(Y_{t}-Y_{t+1}\right)
$$

Here, $K$ is a constant.
$X$ is a geometric brownian motion. $Y$ is another geometric brownian motion.

Please let me know if anything is not clear.